# Handling an exception when passing an invalid parameter type to a Macro

Tags: c, linux, macros

I am using the following method to use sprintf_s on Linux.

```
#define sprintf_s(buf, size, fmt, ...)      snprintf(buf, size, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

But sometimes I make a mistake to use as below.
In this case, the program crashes.

```
sprintf_s( convertBuffer, "%d", rSC );
```

I would like to avoid using macros with these incorrect parameters.

If I use non-integer data in the position of size, is there any way to know this in advance?

Comment: Perhaps you should check before calling `sprintf_s()`.

Comment: Is there a way to check?
I tried using static_assert, but it did not work.

Comment: If there's no specific reason to use macro, you can convert it to a function. Then you can add checking.

Comment: Your answer is to define a new function, link sprintf_s, and then check the parameters inside the function?
And if the type of the parameter is normal, call snprintf?

Comment: thank you for the reply. I will try this one.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. As far I understand, you need a runtime check.

Comment: The problem is that the format string is passed to the position of the 'int size', and the address of the string is recognized as the size.
Is there a way to determine if this data is a string or a regular integer using the 'int size' parameter within my function?

Comment: I think no. But, if `const char*` is passed at the place of `int` , shouldn't compiler warn about it? Have you looked at the recent implementation of `snprintf` or alike functions? I haven't found `sprint_s` on recent kernels.